# DBMS: If more than one multivalued attributes are assigned for an entity how many tables have to be created?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Suppose an entity has following attributes (sno, name, phNo, add).
sno - is primary key.
phNo and add are multi valued attributes.

In this case are 3 tables required? 
 1. sno, name
 2. sno, phNo
 3. sno, add

Answer (score 0):

In 3rd normal form or higher, 3 tables are required.  Denormalized data could be represented in fewer tables, at the risk of update anomalies.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11092494)

Comment: @SnareChops I revised my answer.